# can't install app using it's installer or through commands

Tags: software-installation, software-center

i'm trying to install team viewer on Ubuntu 17.04 the site says if the installer doesn't execute then try right clicking and opening through software installation , and open with ubuntu software center , both of which are not options anywhere

so i tried running the command :
 `sudo apt install teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb` 
but I got this as a response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb'
```

doesn't this command look for it online ?why can't it be found

also i tried moving to my downloads directory and running the command again , same result

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using 
`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`

If you want to install it using `apt-get install package_name`, you first need to move your deb file to `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory. After executing this command, it will automatically download its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

`apt` searches the repositories that you have setup in software sources to locate packages. It can't find the teamviewer package unless you have updated your list of sources to include a PPA which has it. The easiest method is to [download the Ubuntu package](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) and install it with gdebi.

`gdebi [package.deb]` where [package.deb] is the path/to/and name of the deb file you downloaded (currently `teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386` ).